# How can i modify a table in design mode in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I used to modify the tables in SQL Server 2005 but now after creating a table, I want to alter some entites but the SQL Server 2008 never let me do it.

Is it about the configuration scope of the SQL Server 2008? or How ?

Regards
Bk

Comment: right click table -> design . and do the modification to entities .do you want this one ??

Comment: How are you trying to edit it? What messages do you get when you try to edit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that you are using SQL Server Management Studio. In the `Tools - Options` menu, select the `Designers` node, and under `Table options`, uncheck *"Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created"*.

Comment: De nada. Glad to have helped you.